# Jquery var changing doesn't work

Tags: jquery, global, var

it is something stupid for sure but i can't figure it out.
I've set a global variable (i), this should allow me to stop the first function once the second function is activated. However I don't understand why the var value doesn't change from true to false.

```
var i = true;

if (i == true){
$('.projects').hover(function() {
     //do stuff
}, function() {
     //do stuff
});
};

$('.projects').click(function() {
    //do stuff
i = false;  
});
```

Comment: Put your if inside the hover functions, not outside, otherwise the `if` is run only once, when i is true.

Comment: Blind guess: It *does* change, but it doesn't mean prior `if` would run again...

Comment: The JS "if" command is not binded to the condition. It does not work this way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's is way too trivial to be worth an answer

Comment: @ShadowWizard and deletion when it will be closed.

Comment: Friendly tip: learn the basics of JavaScript first. Not jQuery, not advanced stuff, just basics. What are variables, what are conditions, etc. You will find yourself facing far less problems when you'll have the basic knowledge.

Comment: sorry for the waste of time, I know Javascript, it's only been a while since I've been dealing with code. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS

```
var i = true;
$('.projects').hover(function() {
    if (i == true){
         //do stuff
    };
}, function() {
     if (i == true){
         //do stuff
    };
});

$('.projects').click(function() {
    //do stuff
    i = false;  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = true;

$('.projects').hover(function() {
    if(i==true) {
        //do stuff
    };
});

$('.projects').click(function() {
    //do stuff
    i = false;  
});
```

may be you want this ??